# Locale from string

Tags: android, locale

Хочу получить объект `Locale` из строчки вида "ru" или "en" и т.д. Могу ли я как-то это сделать без `if` `else`? Для Android >= 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [доке](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) у класса `Locale` есть конструктор с один аршументом-строкой, которая может быть вида `ru`, `en` etc. Т.е. просто создавайте локаль так:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ru");
```